# current logged in User in Refinery CMS (3.0.0)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I have `Gallery` resource, that was not created as refinery extension. And it must be created/updated by only logged in Users. How can I check if the current user logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem this way: `current_refinery_user.has_role?(:refinery)`

You can also see methods of [NilUser](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-authentication-devise/blob/master/app/models/refinery/authentication/devise/nil_user.rb) and [User](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-authentication-devise/blob/master/app/models/refinery/authentication/devise/user.rb) classes